# JSch Session: Which is better, to create a new instance per request or save it in HttpSession?

Tags: java, ajax, session, jsch

I have a Java web project that executes remote ssh commands using com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.

One module executes scripts to a remote server and writes the output to a logfile in that server. This process takes much time to complete.
For the users to know the progress of the scripts execution, I created a module that connects to remote server, reads the logfile and display it to a webpage using ajax call every 10 seconds.

Which is better:

1. Create a JSch Session and save it to HttpSession and reuse it every ajax requests
2. Create a new JSch Session every subsequent request and close it after use

Answer (score 0):

First,you need to test the time JSch session cost to connect to the remote linux
server.If you think it affects the performance,then you choose to save it in HttpSession.Or perhaps,if all the users request the same linux server.You may save
serveral sessions in the apllication scope instead of Http session scope.From my point of view,since the ajax call is every 10 seconds,it is quite frequent.So,save
the session may be a right choice.You may create something like sessions pool,and it can dynamically increase the size or decrease the size according to the session's timeout.
Make a chice accoring to your needs and do more tests.